# Adding a 1-D Array to a 3-D array in Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I am attempting to add two arrays.

```
np.zeros((6,9,20)) + np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

I want to get something out that is like

```
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
        ..., 
        [ 7.,  7.,  7., ...,  7.,  7.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  8.,  8., ...,  8.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9., ...,  9.,  9.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1., ...,  1.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 2.,  2.,  2., ...,  2.,  2.,  2.],
        [ 3.,  3.,  3., ...,  3.,  3.,  3.],
        ..., 
        [ 7.,  7.,  7., ...,  7.,  7.,  7.],
        [ 8.,  8.,  8., ...,  8.,  8.,  8.],
        [ 9.,  9.,  9., ...,  9.,  9.,  9.]],
```

So adding entries to each of the matrices at the corresponding column. I know I can code it in a loop of some sort, but I am trying to use a more elegant / faster solution.

Comment: What must be the shape of output array?

Comment: For this example, it would need to retain the shape of the 3-D array, so 6,9,20

Comment: You won't get an output like `array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3., ...,  7.,  8.,  9.],...` with that shape `(6,9,20)`, because the last dimension in desired output seems to have 9 elements and not 20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bring [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play after extending the dimensions of the second array with `None` or [`np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis), like so -

```
np.zeros((6,9,20))+np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])[None,:,None]
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, the best thing to use is [NumPy's Broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). You can get what you want with the following:

```
np.zeros((6,9,20))+np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).reshape((1,9,1))
```

I prefer using the [reshape method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) to using slice notation for the indices the way Divakar shows, because I've done a fair bit of work manipulating shapes as variables, and it's a bit easier to pass around tuples in variables than slices. You can also do things like this:

```
array1.reshape(array2.shape)
```

By the way, if you're really looking for something as simple as an array that runs from 0 to N-1 along an axis, check out [mgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html#numpy.mgrid). You can get your above output with just

```
np.mgrid[0:6,1:10,0:20][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tile (but you would also need swapaxes to get the correct shape).

```
A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
B = np.tile(A, (6, 20, 1))
C = np.swapaxes(B, 1, 2)
```